# Use to c# in html to perform if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I've previously seen answers on Stackoverflow that involve using 'the c# construct' to essentially perform an 'if' statement in the html of a asp.net page.

So imagine i want to display Eval("option1") if its not null OR Eval("option2") if option 1 is null. How do i do this???

Hope that makes sense....

Many Thanks!!!!

Comment: This question has over 12K views and yet only 2 people have upped it. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need if statement for it. Just use

```
<%= Eval("option1") ?? Eval("option2") %>
```

Comment: Hey Lloyd, Could you possibly ellaborate on this a little. Its a lot more compact than the example I seem to recall. Why the two question marks? Is this equivalent to null ? Ideally i actually need to check for an empty string rather than null. Thanks

Comment: You looking at C# code inside the <% tag.  The ?? is the null coalescing operator.  In that case `a ?? b === (a != null) ? a : b === if(a != null) return a; else return b`

Comment: Brian, it's not 100% correct. In your description a is calculated 2 times, but it does't.

Answer (score 17):

Is this the "if" semantics you are looking for?

```
<% if (condition == true) { %>
  Show something
<% } else { %>
  Show something else
<%} %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm after c# / Asp.Net.

Comment: ... Is this not C# embedded in ASP code?  I am confused.  Are you looking for this?  http://www.808.dk/?code-aspnet-inline

Comment: now I'm confused. Nothing to do with asp. I am using Asp.Net with C# in a ListView.

Comment: This is not the "if" semantics we are looking for! Move along. Move along. ;-)