# How to do switch statement in aspx page with c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, switch-statement, case

I am working on a legacy website. One of the main web application was written in C# and compiled as a dll, which basically is a black box to us. The application itself is working fine but lacks of expandability. Given enough time, we'd like to re-write the whole thing in php or python. But right now we are trying to find a workaround.

For example, we want to replace the output  `<%=NewKindName()%>` into something new. I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169665/use-to-c-sharp-in-html-to-perform-if-statement) for building an if statement in aspx, but what we really need is more likely to be a switch case statement. I know how to do that in cpp and c#, but have no idea how to insert them into asp.

Thanks,

==============update==========
Here's what I got:

```
<script runat=server>
private string getSwitch(string param)
{
string NewNewKindName=null;
switch (param)
    {
        case "aa":
            NewNewKindName= "AA" ;
            break;

        case "bb":
            NewNewKindName= "BB" ;
            break;      
        case "cc":
            NewNewKindName= "CC" ;
            break;

        case "dd":
            NewNewKindName= "DD" ;
            break;
        default :
            NewNewKindName= "EE" ;
            break;      
    }
    return NewNewKindName;
}
</script>
```

And call `<%=getSwitch(NewKindName())%>` in html

Comment: What exactly didn't work for you? What did you get? Any errors reported (which one(s))?

Comment: It works now, I've posted the code in update.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "=" character in your example <%= %>, thus:

```
<%

// Add code here
switch() // you know...

// To response to HTML do, for example:
Response.Write(NewKindName());

%>
```